# Multi activity management with tab bar and bottom bar

Tags: android

I recently use AHBottomNavigation which have 5 item in bottom bar for example when 
I click Home Button it goes to homeActivty which I have 3 tab bar. Everything until here is ok but I realize when we use AHBottomNavigation we should use fragment but 
I need to use activities with bars and show AHBottomNavigation in all of them. 
I use AHBottomNavigation in all of my activities to handle this and it work's and all of my activities have AHBottomNavigation but when i change activities, 
AHBottomNavigation doesnt work as good as normal and it seems that there is a delay in it. 
Is there any better solution for this or please inform me if I'm doing something wrong ?

HomeActivity.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        if (drawer != null) {
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        }
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //[START Tab ]
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //[*End Tab]

        //[Start Bottom N]
        bottomNavigation();

    }

        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(),"Tab1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2() , "Tab2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3() , "Tab3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
     public void bottomNavigation(){
        // [START  BottomNavigation]
        // TODO add other activitys to setOnTabSelectedListener (HOME , SEARCH , ...)
        AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        // Create items

        AHBottomNavigationAdapter navigationAdapter = new AHBottomNavigationAdapter(this, R.menu.bottom_navigation);
        navigationAdapter.setupWithBottomNavigation(bottomNavigation);


        bottomNavigation.setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(true);
        bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#3498db"));
        bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(0);

        bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {


                switch (position){
                    case 0 :

                        break;
                    case 1 :
                        // Add
                        Intent goToAddStuff = new Intent(HomeActivity.this , AddStuffActivity.class);
                        startActivity(goToAddStuff);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case 2 :
                        // Search
                        break;
                    case  3:
                        // Activity's
                    //My AONActivity have 2 tab too
                        Intent goToAON = new Intent(HomeActivity.this , AONActivity.class);
                        startActivity(goToAON);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case  4:
                        //Account
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        // [*END  BottomNavigation]
    }
```

content_home.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
android:id="@+id/content_id"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</RelativeLayout>



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBar" />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottom_navigation.xml

```
<com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation

    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

</com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation>
```

Comment: consider share your code for a better undestanding

Answer (score 1):

I also use AHBottomNavigation but you need due to Google Material Design you need to use Fragments, otherwise you implement it incorrect.

Here how it should be :

```
<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is some code just to show how is better to work with fragments if you have no idea, just I do not know your background and maybe you do not use it because you feel confused with this.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Position " + position + " was selected" + wasSelected);
    if(!wasSelected) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(FRAME_LAYOUT,
                        createFragment(position),
                        createItemDescription(position))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}

private void createBottomNavigationMenu(int defaultCurrentItem){

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        //  Create bottom navigation item
        AHBottomNavigationItem item =
                new AHBottomNavigationItem(createItemDescription(i),
                                            createPicture(i));
        //  Add bottom navigation item
        mBottomNavigation.addItem(item);
    }

 //  Set current item programmatically
    mBottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(defaultCurrentItem, true);

 //  Set background color
     mBottomNavigation.setDefaultBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#56ABF8"));

  //  Disable the translation inside the CoordinatorLayout
    mBottomNavigation.setBehaviorTranslationEnabled(false);

  //  Set listener
    mBottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
}

 // Factory-method patterns
private Fragment createFragment(int position){
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            return new SettingsFragment_();
        case 2:
            return new StatisticsFragment_();
        case 3:
            return new MainFragment_();
        case 4:
            return new ForthFragment_();
        case 5:
            return new ReminderFragment_();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

private String createItemDescription(int position){
    switch (position){
        case 1:
            return BOT_NAV_ITEM_SETTINGS;
        case 2:
            return BOT_NAV_ITEM_STATISTICS;
        case 3:
            return BOT_NAV_ITEM_MAIN;
        case 4:
            return BOT_NAV_ITEM_FORTH;
        case 5:
            return BOT_NAV_ITEM_REMINDERS;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}

private int createPicture(int position){
    switch (position){
        case 1:
            return R.mipmap.ic_settings;
        case 2:
            return R.mipmap.ic_statistics;
        case 3:
            return R.mipmap.ic_water;
        case 4:
            return R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        case 5:
            return R.mipmap.ic_reminders;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the **Solution** :

I create HomeFragment which extent fragment like this :

> HomeFragment.class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;

    private static int currentItem = 0;
    AdapterFragment adapter;

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
        HomeFragment frag = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("tab", someInt);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("currentItem", viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
        HomeFragment frag = new HomeFragment();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter= new AdapterFragment(getChildFragmentManager());
        currentItem=getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("tab") : 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Adapter for the View Pager
         */
        if (adapter==null) adapter=new AdapterFragment(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem( currentItem);

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }

    public class AdapterFragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AdapterFragment(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new Tab1Fragment();
                case 1 : return new Tab2Fragment();
                case 2 : return new Tab3Fragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 3;

        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Tab1";
                case 1 :
                    return "Tab2";
                case 2 :
                    return "Tab3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And in my

> MainActivity

```
bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {

                switch (position){
                    case 0 :
                        // Home
                        HomeFragment homeFragment = new  HomeFragment();
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.content_id, homeFragment)
                                .commit();


                        break;
                    case 1:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Not the best solution to keep TabLayout and ViewPager as static variables. It will be a cause of memory leaks, and we need to avoid such behavior.